# Not able use get the locally made application setting from class library using C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, class-library

I have c# class library in VS 2017 version. I wanted get certain information while I execute my application dynamically. So I have created settings.setting file which inturn created app.config file.

In my settings file a created variable **ENV** and provided value as **Production**. And built the DLL. In my package I have DLL and a config files respectively.

So if users wants to run the application and connect with Test Environment. The user goes to the locally saved config file and changes the value to **Test** and saves the file & runs the application.

I expect the application to run in Test Environment. But even inspite of changing the **ENV** value in config file. It still connects to **Production**.

What am I actually missing here?

Comment: In the Settings tab in the IDE, what did you set the scope of the "ENV" setting to? And what is the name of the locally-saved config file that you're editing?

Comment: In the VS,I have selected type as "string" and selected scope as "user". And I also have selected scope as "application" as well and tried.Both option didn't work when I try to make changes in config file. And whenever I perform the build the project . It creates a DLL with the solution name and also a config file with name of DLL  .Example if my DLL name generated is "mycustom.dll" it would also create a config like "my custom.dll.config" .